# Disable dedicated video card without installing drivers

Tags: 12.10, ati, graphics

So, Ubuntu doesn't come with drivers for my ATI Radeon HD 5650 (mobility), and I tried about 3 different drivers, and all failed.

My question is, can I just disable my ATI video card and use the onboard one, without installing the ATI drivers? And how? (I heard nVidia cards allow this if you have the software and driver installed)

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is an option for this in BIOS?

Comment: I have the same graphics card and the proprietary AMD drivers are running fine over here (Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS). However, I had to disable the integrated card first in my BIOS as hybrid setups with HD5xxx cards are not supported by FGLRX. After setting the BIOS up in this way I simply followed the instructions outlined in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200).

Answer (score 0):

http://planetoss.com/articles/how-to-disable-the-discrete-amd-graphics-card-in-linux/
Follow this article and you can disable it.

in short

```
sudo -s
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

See the difference of the cat, you can see that the dedicated card "DIS" is "Off" instead of "Pwr"

If it really works and you want to disable it on every startup, modify "etc/rc.local". Just follow the article I posted above.